# React push history does not rendering

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

New to react, i use redux, hooks to create login and dashboard pages. When using history.push('/'), my app does not render corresponding component, please view below the different parts :

```
// App/App.jsx
...
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import { LoginPage } from '../LoginPage';
import { history } from '../_helpers';
function App() {
    <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact={true} path="/" render={() => (
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
            )} />
            <Route path="/login" component={ LoginPage } />
            <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
}
export {App}
```

**Now on my entry point page :**

```
// index.jsx
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { App } from './App';
import { store } from './_helpers'

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Login component where react hook is used, for simplicity i just add here important parts :

```
// src > LoginPage > LoginPage.jsx
import { userActions } from '../_actions';
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(email && password) {
        dispatch(userActions.login(email,password));
    }
}
return(
    <form name="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="email" 
            name="email" 
            onChange={(event) => inputChangeHandler(event)} />
        <input type="password" 
            name="password" 
            onChange={(event) => inputChangeHandler(event)} />
        <button className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
);
```

Actions component where i also call API services and push history to change page :

```
// src > _actions > user.actions.jsx
...
import { history } from '../_helpers';
import { userService } from '../_services';
function login(email, password) {
    return dispatch => {
        userService.login(email, password)
        .then(user => { 
            dispatch(success(user));
            history.push('/'); // <<< push history
         },
         error => {
             .... handle errors here
         })
    }
}
....
```

And the last one, the history file
// src > _helpers > helpers.jsx
...
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export const history = createBrowserHistory();

As you see, after login success i want to change page from (my_domain.com/login) to my_domain.com/), but the component is not rendered, it remains to the login page even the browser displays the good url : my_domain.com/

Sorry for my bad english, but if you want more informations to help, thanks to letting me know.

So if anyone can help me solve this problem, I'm grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: If you're using a custom history object then I think you just want `Router` - not `BrowserRouter as Router`. The `BrowserRouter` option is only for interacting with the HTML5 history API.

Comment: You are just awesome, thank's for your light.